# SAPUI5 > 1.30, how to set custom model headers before initial request

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

Before the use of a manifest file I used to add custom headers to the config of my oData model. Now starting from SAPUI5 1.30 the Component.js is using a manifest file and as soon as the runtime enters the Component.js init() function the model is already loaded and a first request is already made to my service.
I need a way to set my custom headers at runtime and before the first request to my service is made.

Before:

```
    // The service URL for the oData model
    var oServiceConfig = this.getMetadata().getConfig().serviceConfig;
    var sServiceUrl = oServiceConfig.serviceUrl;

    // the metadata is read to get the location of the i18n language files later
    var mConfig = this.getMetadata().getConfig();
    this._routeMatchedHandler = new sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler(this.getRouter(), this._bRouterCloseDialogs);

    // create oData model
    this._initODataModel(sServiceUrl);

// _initODataModel function

    headers = {custom: 'hello world'};
    var oConfig = {
        metadataUrlParams: {},
        json: true,
        // loadMetadataAsync : true,
        defaultBindingMode: "OneWay",
        defaultCountMode: "Inline",
        useBatch: true,
        headers: headers
    };

    var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, oConfig);       
    this.setModel(oModel);
```

Comment: Can you add some code? Currently I think what you did without manifest was passing metadataUrlParams before loading the model? I think in manifest this also exists.. "models":  --> "" --> Settings --> metadataUrlParams ... in JSON Style.

Comment: @zyrax Sorry if I was not clear, I need to calculate my header values at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

The manifest.json file aka app descriptor is not as dynamic as you would need it. In other words: you can't achieve what you want using the app descriptor. This is a drawback of using the app descriptor.

You could use your Component.js instead to have something dynamic. In there you could instantiate you model manually... Maybe you could also configure the component the "old" way without the manifest.json file.

Answer (score 0):

you can specify the object that is passed to the models constructor in the [manifest.json](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html) in *sap.ui5/models/myModel/settings*:

```
"sap.app": {
  "dataSources": {
    "myDatasource": {
      "uri": "/sap/hba/r/apf/core/odata/apf.xsodata",
      "type": "OData",
      "settings": {
         "odataVersion": "2.0"
      }
    }
  }
},
"sap.ui5": {
  "models": {
     "myModel": {
        "datasource": "myDatasource",
        "settings": {
          "headers": {
             "headername1":"headervalue1",
             "headername2":"headervalue2",
          }
        }
     }
  }  
}
```

Comment: from my Point of view this is exactly the same Thing you did before. You passed the headers during init of the model. this is the same in app descriptor language... maybe I dont get the Point? but is think you cant do it at runtime, now I got it. But oData Model has a method "setHeaders" ... maybe this helps?

Comment: The manifest.json does not support dynamic configuration. The manifest ist read and the models are initialized before the init() method is called so you can neither influence the model instantiation nor modify the manifest data beforehand. You have to instantiate the model your self in the init() method. You could of corse still define the datasource in the manifest and [read the values like uri from the manifest](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.Component.html#getManifestEntry) in the init() method to configure your model with.